# Location permission compilation error

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-gps, runtime-permissions

I am making sure I have permission here:

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        getLocation();
    }
}

private void getLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new UserLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, this);
}
```

But I am still getting a compilation error for the requestLocationUpdates() call:

```
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`
```

The error is resolved when I remove the function call like so:

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new UserLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, this);
    }
}
```

However I need the getLocation function to also be called in the onRequestPermissionsResult callback, so I would like to keep it.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

How is this typically resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It is a nightmare managing these permissions like that. I would recommend you to use this library to take care of all boilerplate stuff.
You can do this with a very little knowledge of RXJava
https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions

```
compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.9.3@aar'
```

and then:

```
final String permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
rxPermissions
.request(permission)
.switchMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(Boolean permissionGranted) {
        if (permissionGranted) {
            //todo: do stuff require permissions.
        } else {
            rxPermissions.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission).switchMap(
            new Func1<Boolean, Observable<Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Boolean> call(Boolean canShowRationale) {
                    if (canShowRationale) {
                        /**
                         * when user deny permission,Show dialog explaining why permission is
                         * necessary. On Selecting Ask again, permission access will be
                         * re-requested.
                         */

                        //todo: 
                    } else {
                        /**
                         * When user deny permission and select Never Ask Again, Show dialog
                         * explaining why permission are necessary. In this case user need to
                         * go to settings and grant permission.
                         */

                        //todo: 
                    }
                }
            });
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: awesome. I'd love to check that out but my boss hates anything third party.

Comment: Ah ok sure. I just modified the example with location request

Comment: "my boss hates anything third party". Unless you work in a very specific environment that justifies such aversion, your boss needs to realize that all apps use third party libraries, and that it is the only way to get stuff out quickly, and with less code to maintain yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For non-reactive approach, this library would be great help which use simple annotation-based API to handle runtime permissions:

https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher

```
@RuntimePermissions
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void showCamera() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, CameraPreviewFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack("camera")
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    @OnShowRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void showRationaleForCamera(final PermissionRequest request) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(R.string.permission_camera_rationale)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, (dialog, button) -> request.proceed())
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, (dialog, button) -> request.cancel())
            .show();
    }

    @OnPermissionDenied(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void showDeniedForCamera() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_camera_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @OnNeverAskAgain(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void showNeverAskForCamera() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_camera_neverask, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```